# Unable to read file from server

Tags: android

I want to download file from server. File is created successfully in my android device but that file is empty file. it is not writing anything in file.

My filereading code is as follows:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        //connect
        urlConnection.connect();

        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //create a new file, to save the downloaded file
        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,pos);

        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //Stream used for reading the data from the internet
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        //this is the total size of the file which we are downloading
        totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

        //create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;

        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
        }
        fileOutput.close();

}
```

I have debugged the code. There is something wrong in  while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) condition as the compiler didnt go inside this loop.

My log cat error:

```
ERROR/ActivityThread(8218): Activity com.sec.android.app.myfiles.DetailsActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.sec.android.app.myfiles.DetailsActivity$4@42760570 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
        android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.sec.android.app.myfiles.DetailsActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.sec.android.app.myfiles.DetailsActivity$4@42760570 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:792)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:593)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1254)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1241)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1235)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:372)
        at 

    com.sec.android.app.myfiles.DetailsActivity.setLocaleReceiver(DetailsActivity.java:185)
            at com.sec.android.app.myfiles.DetailsActivity.onCreate(DetailsActivity.java:121)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you specified write permission to the sd card in the manifest file..?

Comment: yes i have specified write permission

Comment: You need to use a BufferInputStream : BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputstream); and read from that :

Answer (score 0):

Use Asynctask to download file from server this is the code to download a file from server with Progress dialog and works fine.. please try it..

```
 package .....;


    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;


     public class facebook1 extends Activity {

        Button btnShowProgress;

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        public static final int progress_bar_type = 0; 




        private static String file_url = "yoururl";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.layout);

            btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit1);

            btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);


                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case progress_bar_type:
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait.....");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setMax(100);
                pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
                return pDialog;
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }

        class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


            protected static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 0;

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                showDialog(progress_bar_type);
            }

            /**
             * Downloading file in background thread
             * */
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
                int count;
                try {

                    URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                    URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                    conection.connect();

                    int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

                    File downloadloc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(downloadloc
                            + "/filenam.ext"); //type the name of file with extension.

                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                    long total = 0;

                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;

                        publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }

                    output.flush();

                    output.close();
                    input.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                }

                return null;
            }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
                pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);





            }}

}
```

Manifest File:

```
<uses-permission 
         android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
         > </uses-permission>
```

Comment: sir i am using async task and i copy paste your code accroding to my requirements but still file is not reading

Comment: in your above code the issue is with output.write(). its not writing file

Comment: the file i am trying to get from server is GIS file

Comment: can you please post the logcat

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

to

```
String SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
```

Comment: I had an issue similar to yours... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850608/android-sdcard-doesnt-create-copy-a-file It's solved

Comment: sir the issue is this the compiler is not getting into while loop

Answer (score 0):

Starting from API 14, Network operations are not supported in the main Thread. Try using AsyncTask if you are doing it in the main Thread and using 14 or higher version of SDK.